# Format text file using Python or Excel

Tags: python-2.7, excel, format, vba

I have a text file that looks like:

```
ROOT: are   DOBJ: money DOBJ: deal  
DOBJ: products  ROOT: count DOBJ: me    DOBJ: deal  
POBJ: amp   ROOT: dads. POBJ: diapers   
ROOT: get   DOBJ: ecard DOBJ: it    
ROOT: hutang
```

Each word is seperated by a tab. The file has about 50,000 lines like this. I want to format the file in such a way that each line starts with a ROOT followed by DOBJ, and then by POBJ. Every line has exactly one ROOT and the count of DOBJ/POBJ is unknown and can vary from 0-5. I tried to import the file into an excel sheet and trying doing a HLOOKUP but I am not getting what I want. I want to write the following logic in VBA (I have never used VBA before):

```
Dim sh As Worksheet
Dim rw As Range
Dim RowCount As Integer

Set sh = ActiveSheet
For Each rw In sh.Rows
    if cellnumber(ROOT) != A
        swap content(A), content of cell containing ROOT
```

Can someone help me with this code or tell me if there is a better way to do it either using Python or Excel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In VBA, this should help you to get started.

```
Sub test()
Dim InputString As String
Dim RowToPerform As Long
Dim TextPath As Variant
Dim ArrayString() As String
Dim CounterArray As Long

TextPath = Application.GetOpenFilename("Txt Files,*.txt", Title:="Select Txt")
Open TextPath For Input As #1
    Do Until EOF(1)
        Line Input #1, InputString
        RowToPerform = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
        'ArrayString = Split(InputString, "|")
        ArrayString = Split(InputString, "ROOT:")
        Cells(RowToPerform, 1).Value = "ROOT: "
        Cells(RowToPerform - 1, 1).Value = Cells(RowToPerform - 1, 1).Value & ArrayString(0)
        For CounterArray = LBound(ArrayString) To UBound(ArrayString)
        If CounterArray > 0 Then Cells(RowToPerform, 1).Value = Cells(RowToPerform, 1).Value & ArrayString(CounterArray)
        Next CounterArray
    Loop
    Close #1
End Sub
```

[These](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/ImpText.aspx) [links](http://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/read-data-from-text-file.html) may be useful as well.
[image]